# Web driver is not closed even after using driver.quit()

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

ChromeBrower is not closing after the test execution

Please check the code in the attached picture [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24kzM.png) after the method code.!!

Please help me to resolve this.!! Thanks in advance

My Chrome driver should be closed after test execution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: added snap shot of my code.!! please click on the CODE hyperlink to view it

Comment: is the code reaching this method during execution, have you tried placing a debug point and checking that, is there any exception on the console